# make link clickables with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to make my links automatically clickables, but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
$val['message'] = preg_replace('#https?://(w{3}.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,20}(.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,10}))(/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,12}(/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,12}))?(/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,20})(.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,7}))?(\?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,7}=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,7}(&[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,7}=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,7}))?#is', '$0', $val['message']);
```

(here is my preg thing, but with lines:)

```
'https?://
    (w{3}.)?
    ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,20}(.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,10}))
    (/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,12}(/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,12}))?
    (/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,20})
    (.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,7}))?
    (\?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,7}=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,7}
    (&[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,7}=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,7}))?
```

I also tried this:

```
$val['message'] = preg_replace("#(([\w]+?://[\w#$%&~.-;:=,?@[]+])(/[\w#$%&~/.-;:=,?@[]+])?)#is", "$1", $val['message']);
```

but doesn't work with links like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videolink`

Comment: How about something like this, https://regex101.com/r/kG4zF7/1?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex, worked for me:

```
(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?
```

Comment: I'm using preg_replace("#((?:ht)tps?://[^\s]+?)(\s|$)#i", '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>'); and it doesn't work with the link  https://www.mediafire.com/download/y68a2fad7em48pk/GMZFinalIntro.rar

Answer (score 1):

Why does everyone like to try to make their own regex for this? Linkifying links is hard work with lots of edge cases, not to mention what should or shouldn't be included in the link, e.g.

> Are you talking about youtube.com?
>
> I like the ASP.net language
>
> I wonder what www.stackoverflow.com counts as a link
>
> Parentheses are a particular pain in the butt (example: http://example.com/?auth=gH;2($Hd)DA0;QAb)

Aside: in the last line above, StackOverflow's preview section links everything until the last closing bracket, but after submission it only links up to the first <s>punctuation mark</s> bracket. Helps prove my point about how hard this is to get right and consistent though!

Best to use something established, example:

https://github.com/misd-service-development/php-linkify

For something a bit more quick n dirty:

http://buildinternet.com/2010/05/how-to-automatically-linkify-text-with-php-regular-expressions/